# How do I change a parameter in a method to accept different classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I change the entity parameter in the below method so it can accept me passing either `class1` or `class2` to save to the database using EF?

```
public class class1
{
     string name {get; set;}
     string value {get; set;}
}

public class class2
{
     string city {get; set;}
     string money {get; set;}
}

private static financeEntities AddToContext(financeEntities context, **Class1 entity**, int count, int commitCount, bool recreateContext, string market)
{
     context.Set<Class1>().Add(entity);
     context.SaveChanges();

     return context;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into generics. Basically, if you understand how to instantiate a `List<T>`, you're already working with generics and you probably understand its usage. MSDN has a lot of articles that can help you to leverage this for your own needs.

Comment: @code4life So do I just change the parameter to class<DbSet>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddToContext` method should be a generic one.

```
private static financeEntities AddToContext<T>(financeEntities context, T entity //, ...) 
    where T : class
{
    context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return context;
}
```

And then call as:

```
AddToContext<class1>(..)
AddToContext<class2>(..)
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting this error
The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()

Comment: You need generic constraint on method. I have updated method signature in answer.